# How do you specify for CPLEX to use only one thread in pyomo?

Tags: python-3.x, cplex, pyomo

How do you specify for CPLEX to use only one thread in pyomo?

CPLEX [by default](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/parallel_optim/multi_threaded_parallel/05_thread_params.html) uses up to 32 threads, capped by the number of processors. But how do you specify using `pyomo` to only use one thread?

Assume my code already has the following:

```
import pyomo
cplex_solver = pyomo.opt.SolverFactory('cplex')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[IBM says](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/parallel_optim/multi_threaded_parallel/05_thread_params.html) its CPLEX thread count parameter is called `Threads`.

I tried

```
import pyomo
cplex_solver = pyomo.opt.SolverFactory('cplex')
cplex_solver.options['threads'] = 1
```

and it has successfully made CPLEX use only one thread.

Comment: This is generally what has to be done for all solving parameters of all solvers (Going to solver's documentations and using the `solver.options['option name']` line). So +1 for providing a method to find the parameter that works for *all* solvers and parameters.